# displaying empty results C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Guys i am using the following code but it displaying no output and not showing any error. Please help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    //Display each port name to the console.
    foreach (string port in ports)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(port);
        //_serialport.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with debug points? do you get values to `ports0` ?

Comment: What does "displaying no output" mean? Assuming that you display your ListBox, and it comes out empty: `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` could be empty, you should check that first.

Comment: Dear @TheHowlingHoaschd you are right. serialport.GetportNames() is empty. It is not getting any value. But the same code is running in another laptop. How can i fix it??

Comment: @m.asghar Sorry for the late answer. I don't know actually. I recommend checking the network configuration of your maching, and comparing it with the machine, where it's working on (just a layman's advice though). Additionally try googling what can cause such behaviour in this function. If all that fails, update your question here, or close it and open a new one, if it's sufficiently different.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace listSerial
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = null;
            try
            {
                names = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            if(names!=null)
            {
                int portnum = names.Length;
                if (portnum != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NO_COM");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to answer the question? or at least help people with the same problem? Code without comments or text looks frankly arbitrary.